# Docker service exits with exit code 0 - Nuls CHAINBOX

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, blockchain

Docker service exits with exit code 0 - Nuls CHAINBOX

The docker exit when the start command is executed.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

RUN yum -y install git
RUN yum -y install wget 
RUN yum -y install maven
RUN yum -y install java-11-openjdk

RUN mvn -version

ARG JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.el7_7.x86_64
ARG JRE_HOME="$JAVA_HOME" 
ARG JAVA_HOME="$JRE_HOME"
ARG MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven

ENV JAVA_HOME "$JRE_HOME" 
ENV MAVEN_HOME="$MAVEN_HOME"
ENV PATH "$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

RUN git clone https://github.com/lijunzhou/nuls-engine.git chainbox

RUN ./chainbox/example/package
RUN ./chainbox/tools -p example

EXPOSE 22 443 80 8000 8080 9418
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  chain:
    build:
      context: "../"
      dockerfile: "./Dockerfile"
    container_name: "CHAIN"
    command: bash -c "./chainbox/NULS-WALLET/start-dev"
    # volumes:
    #   - "../NULS-WALLET:/chainbox/NULS-WALLET"
```

Result

```
marcelo@M yml % docker-compose up
Starting CHAIN ... done
Attaching to CHAIN
CHAIN    | LOG PATH    : /chainbox/NULS-WALLET/Logs
CHAIN    | DATA PATH   : /chainbox/NULS-WALLET/data
CHAIN    | CONFIG FILE : /chainbox/NULS-WALLET/nuls.ncf
CHAIN    | DEBUG       : 0
CHAIN    | JAVA_HOME   : /chainbox/NULS-WALLET/Libraries/JAVA/JRE/11.0.2
CHAIN    | openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
CHAIN    | OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
CHAIN    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
CHAIN    | 
CHAIN    | ====================
CHAIN    | NULS-WALLET STARTING
CHAIN    | ====================
CHAIN exited with code 0
```

Comment: If you ran that command from a shell prompt, would it immediately return (possibly launching a background process)?  If so, it will always do this if you try to use it as the main process in a Docker container.  Don't use a "start" script; directly launch the process as a foreground process (as the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, preferably).

Comment: CMD bash -c "./chainbox/NULS-WALLET/start-dev" ?

Comment: That script can't be the main container process.